# How to create a type that can hold values like UInt but also additional value 00?

Tags: swift

I have an issue when trying to create a type that would hold a specific set of values. It's for a basketball app.

Basketball players have jersey numbers. In some European countries (as is the case for this app), the numbers range from 0 to 99 inclusive. But there's also an additional value 00 that's available and it's not the same thing as 0.

I can use String for that, but then String can store other values and I'd have to write additional validation code.

For now I'm using an UInt to store the numbers.

Is there any better way to store such values as a Swift type?

Comment: Increase the range to be 0 to 100 and let 100 be that special number. Then add some logic when displaying it so 100 is displayed as 00

Comment: It would help a lot if we could see this special "type" that you're creating. How are you restricting the numbers to the range 0...99 in the first place?

Comment: @matt for now it's a UInt without any upper bound checking as it's not that critical, I've edited the question

Comment: Okay, so "create a type" in your question title and in the body of the question is not really true? That's fine, just trying to get clear. If you want to use a plain UInt, that's fine. You can just extend it to "translate" itself into a string in the way that Joakim Danielson suggests.

Comment: A tangent to your question, but I thought jersey numbers could only have numbers made up from the digits zero-through-five.

Comment: @PhillipMills yes, that's the rule in NBA, but for example FIBA has 4...15, and in some European leagues you can use 00, 0...99

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an excellent use case for a custom type. It is definitely not a UInt, or any kind of integer. Is #23 + #24 = #47? That's gibberish. What's #99 * #2? Again, gibberish. This isn't an integer.

Just to carry this one step further, while "00" is a legal Jersey number, "01" is not. That's not just the same as "1". It's not a valid number. In fact, if this is NCAA, [*most* numbers aren't legal](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/BR13.pdf) (see section 5 article 5.b.2).

Instead, JerseyNumber is its own type. It has its own legal operations (in technical terms, it has its own algebra).

The most sensible primitive type to use for JerseyNumber is String, since you want to be able to distinguish 00 from 0. I would probably implement it this way, which will give you Equatable, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible, and a more convenient Codable:

```
struct JerseyNumber: Hashable {
    private var string: String

    static let legalNumbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "00", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55"]

    init?(_ string: String) {
        guard JerseyNumber.legalNumbers.contains(string) else { return nil }
        self.string = string
    }
}

extension JerseyNumber: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { string }
}

extension JerseyNumber: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let value = try container.decode(String.self)
        guard let number = JerseyNumber(value) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container,
                                                   debugDescription: "Could not decode JerseyNumber: \(value)")
        }
        self = number
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(string)
    }
}
```

Obviously if this isn't NCAA, or if you want other rules for your numbers, you can rework `init` to enforce that or not enforce in whatever way makes sense for your problem. You can, for example, parse the string rather than having a big list of legal values. This is just an example. But the underlying point is to use a custom type for this, not UInt.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was thinking of. Thoughts: Maybe some sort of dependency injection (I hate that term) could be used to implement european vs. US numbering rules. Also I think you should show how to generate the `legalNumbers` _by rule_, i.e., using code that expresses what the rules are, rather than an apparently arbitrary error-prone manual list of values.

Comment: In the case of the NCAA rules, I'd say this approach is the least error-prone because it's copied directly from the rules (which enumerate the exact allowed numbers). Working out an algorithm that matches those numbers rather than just listing the rule as stated is where error is likely to come in. But certainly, in other environments it could be useful to create a generic form like `struct JerseyNumber<Rule: RuleSet>` where `RuleSet` was a protocol that provided `static func isValid(string: String) -> Bool`.

Comment: The big tradeoff of making this more customizable is that it makes serialization hard. If you know that only one rule system exists in your program, then you can encode numbers as just a string. But if there could be different rules, you may need to encode their type when you serialize. I'd wait until there were a real need for that before implementing it.

Comment: This looks good @RobNapier, thank you. I also see how it can be easily adapted to other numbering rules by following @matt's suggestion to generate `legalNumbers` and make it more testable. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Why not a set instead of an array? Looks like the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum like:

```
enum JerseyNumber {
   case jersey(UInt)
   case special //You could call this doubleZero
}
```

This would allow you to store the Jersey numbers and this special 00 number.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of restricting the range of the UInt?

Comment: Does it say the numbers have to be restricted though? The question mentions the range, but the actual question is how to store these values.

Comment: @matt restricting the range of Uint wasn't the issue I was concerned about, it was predominantly about the ability to distinguish between 0 and 00

Answer (score 1):

You could define a string type enum and list the legal values explicitly:

```
enum JerseyNumber: String {
    case jersey00 = "00"
    case jersey0 = "0"
    case jersey1 = "1"
    case jersey2 = "2"
    case jersey3 = "3"
    case jersey4 = "4"
    case jersey5 = "5"
    //...
    case jersey99 = "99"
    case jersey100 = "100"
}
```

Then, to get the string value of a JerseyNumber:

```
print (JerseyNumber.jersey00.rawValue)
```

(Outputs "00")

And to create a JerseyNumber from a String:

```
if let aJersey = JerseyNumber(rawValue: "5") {
    print(aJersey)
}
```

(outputs "jersey5" {The name of the enum, not it's rawValue} )

Comment: At this point I really don't see why this is better than a validating wrapper on a string.

Comment: It allows you to validate that a given value is allowed, it allows you to use exhaustive switch statements. Why not post an example of a validating wrapper on a String? (Not quite sure what you mean, so I'd like to see it.)

Comment: I think my answer is what @matt is talking about.

Comment: Gotcha. I sorta figured you were talking about a custom type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat different solution using a property wrapper

```
@propertyWrapper struct JerseyNumber {
    var wrappedValue: Int?

    init(_ number: Int) {
        guard (0...100).contains(number) else {
            wrappedValue = nil
            return
        }
        wrappedValue = number
    }

    var projectedValue: String {
        switch wrappedValue {
        case nil: return "not set"
        case 100: return "00"
        default:
            return String(wrappedValue!)
        }
    }
}

    struct Player {
    let name: String
    @JerseyNumber var number: Int?

    var description: String {
        "\(name) \($number)"
    }
}

var team = [
    Player(name: "A", number: JerseyNumber(10)),
    Player(name: "B", number: JerseyNumber(15)),
    Player(name: "C", number: JerseyNumber(3)),
    Player(name: "D", number: JerseyNumber(100)),
    Player(name: "E", number: JerseyNumber(1000)),
]

team.forEach { print($0.name, $0.$number) }
```